# by what tool making this ios class UML graph?

Tags: ios, uml

[image]
1

[image]

2
3
[image]
as title,by what software making this cool graph?
by the way, under mac

---edit

http://www.macresearch.org/files/images/ExpressionClassDiagram.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a data model created by CoreData within XCode.

[image]

Comment: oh yes, but could it generate graph for all classes?(not limited in core data)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this was created by Xcode itself. Xcode versions prior to 4 included the class modeling functionality you see here, which is different than the Core Data Model Editor.

Xcode 4 removed the general class modeling and diagram functionality.